# Incorrect response mime type (Expected 'application/wasm) PSPDFKIT and the reserved size is not enough to contain the signature issue oracle apex?

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I followed the PSPDFKit  Standalone Integration steps ,and all file in public directory (folder "i" in Apache tomcat),

I get the "PSPDFKit for Web successfully loaded!" message but it hangs up and the console gives me a single error :-

```
Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': Incorrect response MIME type. Expected 'application/wasm'.
```

also when i try to add digital signature faced this issue

```
Cannot add the container structure because the reserved size is not enough to contain the signature. Available size 8193, actual size 89694
```

I am tried that by below code

```
PSPDFKit.load({
        container: "#pspdfkit",
        document: 'f?p=&APP_ID.:0:&APP_SESSION.:APPLICATION_PROCESS=PREVIEW_FILE:::FILE_ID:'  + apex.item('P6_ID').getValue(),
        licenseKey: "",
    initialViewState: new PSPDFKit.ViewState({
      showSignatureValidationStatus:
        PSPDFKit.ShowSignatureValidationStatusMode.IF_SIGNED
    }),
     async trustedCAsCallback() {
    
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:90/i/certs/ca.pem");
      const cert = await response.text();
      return [cert];
    }
})   

.then(function(instance) {
    
var item = {
  type: "custom",
  id: "my-button",
  title: "digital sign",
  onPress: function(event) {
      instance
  .signDocument(null, generatePKCS7)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("document signed.");
  })
    

  .catch(error => {
    console.error("The document could not be signed.", error);
  });

  }
};
if (app_user =="aaaa") {
instance.setToolbarItems(function(items) {
  items.push(item);
  return items;
});
}
   function generatePKCS7({ fileContents }) {
  const certificatePromise = fetch("http://localhost:90/i/certs/certificate.pem").then(response =>
    response.text()
  );
  const privateKeyPromise = fetch("http://localhost:90/i/certs/private-key.pem").then(response =>
    response.text()
  );
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Promise.all([certificatePromise, privateKeyPromise])
      .then(([certificatePem, privateKeyPem]) => {
        const certificate = forge.pki.certificateFromPem(certificatePem);
        const privateKey = forge.pki.privateKeyFromPem(privateKeyPem);
        const p7 = forge.pkcs7.createSignedData();
        p7.content = new forge.util.ByteBuffer(fileContents);    
        p7.addCertificate(certificate);
        p7.addSigner({
          key: privateKey,
          certificate: certificate,
          digestAlgorithm: forge.pki.oids.sha256,
          authenticatedAttributes: [
            {
              type: forge.pki.oids.contentType,
              value: forge.pki.oids.data
            },
            {
              type: forge.pki.oids.messageDigest
            },
            {
              type: forge.pki.oids.signingTime,
              Value: new Date()
            }
          ]
        }
           );

        p7.sign({ detached: true })
        
        const result = stringToArrayBuffer(
          forge.asn1.toDer(p7.toAsn1()).getBytes()
        );
        resolve(result);
        
      })
      .catch(reject);
  });
}

function stringToArrayBuffer(binaryString) {
  const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(binaryString.length);
  let bufferView = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  for (let i = 0, len = binaryString.length; i < len; i++) {
    bufferView[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
  }

  return buffer;
}

})

        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error(error.message);
        })
```

```
apex version 19.2 
tomcat 8.5 ,
ords
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the WASM file is not served with the correct content type. The solution is either to fix your server to return the correct content type or disable streaming instantiation for WebAssembly when loading PSPDFKit, as described here: https://pspdfkit.com/guides/web/current/troubleshooting/common-issues/#response-has-unsupported-mime-type-error

In the future, please reach out to https://pspdfkit.com/support/request and our support team will help you in there.